# Listview display immediately after loading page in Django

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying to write a small online store on Django and I have a small problem:
I want to display the `listveiw` immediately after the page loads, but Django does not allow it

I tried to make a display by pressing a button, and it worked, but I would like to make a display as soon as the page loads

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'INDEX'),
    path ('prod/', ListView.as_view(queryset=Product.objects.all(), template_name="mainPage/homePage.html"))

]
```

Can you help me?
my `homePage.html`:

```
{% extends "mainPage/wrapper.html" %}
            {% load static %}
            {% block content %}
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">
            {% for val in object_list %}
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="{{ val.Image_path }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ val.Name }}</h5>
                        <a href="#" class="badge badge-primary">{{ val.Category }}</a>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ val.Description }}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}`
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you say that Django does not allow the page to be displayed? Is there any error you can share?

Comment: @Ralf There are no errors, but I just do not display my List view

Comment: What does it show then? An empty page or something else?

Comment: @Ralf when i try to display a list with the help  
`path('', views.index, name = 'INDEX'),
 path ('prod/', ListView.as_view(queryset=Product.objects.all(), template_name="mainPage/homePage.html")) `
it just doesn't display it

Comment: That does not answer my question. Does it show an empty page in the browser? Or does it show the correct template just without data in it? Or something else?

Comment: @Ralf it show the correct template just without data in it

Comment: show us your `homePage.html` template code

Comment: Do you want the first empty url to show the same list in second url?

Comment: @m51 I add my `homePage.html`